# python render string windows paths

Tags: python

i need render a python path but without double backslashes, for example:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path()
>>> path = Path.cwd()
>>> path
... WindowsPath('C:/Users/Documents/projects')
>>> insert_template = "INSERT INTO TABLE TEST VALUES(%r)" % path
>>> insert_template
... 'INSERT INTO TABLE TEST VALUES('C:\\Users\\Documents\\projects')
```

but a need:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path()
>>> path = Path.cwd()
>>> path
... WindowsPath('C:/Users/Documents/projects')
>>> insert_template = "INSERT INTO TABLE TEST VALUES(%r)" % path
>>> insert_template
... 'INSERT INTO TABLE TEST VALUES('C:\Users\Documents\projects')
```

How to make this without `str.replace('\\', '\')`

Comment: Did you try executing insert_template and then look at the database to see if it got stored correctly?

Comment: The problem is that i not write directly to database, i write a `.sql` file for import directly in sqlite3

Comment: Well once you write the string into the .sql file, it should appear correctly.

Comment: So try that and look at the file you get.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to print() the path you get, you'll find that the double backslashes are not present there, so your path is actually already fine.

They are just there to show how you'd express that string in Python code, as there you need to have double backslashes, as backslashes are escape characters.

```
>>> a = "Foo \\ Bar"
>>> a
'Foo \\ Bar'
>>> print(a)
Foo \ Bar
```

Comment: Need render the string in a variable, not print

Comment: If writes to a buffer (`StringIO`) the string is with double backslases

Comment: I just tried writing a backslash to StringIO buffer and it worked fine. Maybe you looked at the buffer using .getvalue() and got confused because the output showed double backslashes. As I said before, that's just how it would be represented as Python code, the buffer actually has single backslashes.